# How can I find out what token was sent from the transaction "input"?

Tags: usdt, usdc

How can I find out what token was sent from the transaction input?

Example:

This input is from some random transaction. I can find out how many tokens are transferred during the transaction but how can I see what token is being transferred? In my case, I need to know if USDT or USDC are being sent.

```
0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000e59cd29be3be4461d79c0881d238cbe87d64595a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000077359400
```

Comment: input is not enough to know that.. you need transaction and logs

Comment: How can I check what token is being transferred having transaction hash and transaction input through for example Etherscan API?

Comment: one way is to check the destination "to" of the transaction. "to" could be the address of the erc20Token. take care this does not work for internal transfers transactions

Comment: What about web3.js? Is there a simple way of getting what token is transferred using the transaction hash with web3.js?